# How to convert ES6 JSON object to dictionary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, reactjs

I am really new to learning ES6 and JQuery so apologies if I am asking an already duplicated question (didnt find similar questions)

I am currently trying to get the data from the JSON file to work as the following

```
{
     EUR: { code: "EUR", symbol: "&euro;", rate: "5,278.0518", … }
     GBP: { code: "GBP", symbol: "&pound;", rate: "4,640.1577", … }
     USD: { code: "USD", symbol: "&#36;", rate: "6,152.3500", … }
}
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
    this.performSearch()
  }

  performSearch(){
    const urlString = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: urlString,
      success: data => {
        console.log("This is in my data", data["bpi"])
    }
  })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>This is a testing p</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to iterate over my data["bpi"] so that I can iterate over all the keys and values in the dictionary.

However, because the dataType of data["bpi"] is undefined, I cannot use the forEach() method on here.

So how should I approach this without having to hard-code everything? (i.e. it works when I do console.log(data["bpi"]["EUR"]))

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert json object to array using `Object.keys` and iterate on that.

### Example

`Object.keys(data["bpi"]).map(key => data["bpi"][key]).forEach(item => console.log(item))`

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here.

`data["bpi"]` or `data.bpi` should not be undefined. It should be an object with 3 keys in this case.

Check how that data is coming back. If it's coming back as JSON you can call `JSON.parse(data)` to parse the data from a JSON object into a JavaScript object that you can then loop through.

Next, to iterate through the keys in the object -- `data.bpi` -- you can't use `.forEach` because that is an Array method. However, you can use a `for.. in` loop.

As others have stated, you can also use `Object.keys` to convert the object into an array of its and then run `forEach` onthat.

### Example

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
for(var key in parsedData.bpi) {
    // do something here...
}

Object.keys(parsedData.bpi).forEach(key => parsedData.bpi[key] /* do something */ )
```

Answer (score 0):

For iterating over objects you can do it as follows :

```
for(var keys in obj){
      var value = obj[key]
       .....
    }
```

- in ES6 a new method called object.keys method was added which returns all the keys in an object

So

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj)
for(var i =0; i<keys.length; i++){
     var value = obj[keys[i]]
      ....
}
```

Your obj here will be data.bpi or data["bpi"]

Answer (score 0):

I see that many people here use the following method to iterate over your `Object`:

```
for (let i in data.bpi) {
    // Your code
}
```

But should **not** use this method because it will also iterate on all enumerable properties of your object.

So here are better methods to use:

```
let keys = Object.keys(data.bpi)
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let item = data.bpi[i]
}
```

Or

```
let keys = Object.keys(data.bpi)
keys.forEach(e => {
    let item = data.bpi[e]
})
```

Or you can use `for...of`:

```
for (let i of data.bpi) {
    let item = i
}
```